# Handler stopped firing after few minutes on IIS 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, infragistics

In ASP.net MVC, I've created a MVC page for file upload using Infragistics WebUpload with the help of this link [Using the HTTP Handler and Module (igUpload)](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/jQuery/2014.1/CLR4.0/html/igUpload_Using_HTTP_Handler_and_Modules.html).

This page (in new project) is working file without any issue.

This same thing/steps, I also applied on my existing application (Asp.net MVC, IIS7). But problem is that, Handler stored firing after few minutes (sometimes after 3-5 mints). If I upload file without any delay then it can upload 50-60 files without any interceptions. All the steps are almost same in both the application.

I don't know why it is happening. Struggling since last 5 days.

Comment: Can you provide some error log for giving you suggestion . Looks like the file upload restriction error .

Comment: I use Infragistics Log API to do this "http://www.infragistics.com/samples/aspnet/web-upload/client-side-events".

4th File (Error file)
iguploadfileuploading: [ File Path: XP_1.pdf] 4
iguploadfileselected: [ File Path: XP_1.pdf]


2nd File
iguploadfileselecting
iguploadfileuploaded: [ File Size: 33063]
iguploadfileuploading: [ File Path: Consent.pdf] 3
iguploadfileselected: [ File Path: Consent.pdf]


1st file 
iguploadfileselecting
iguploadfileuploaded: [ File Size: 63307]
iguploadfileuploading: [ File Path: asb.pdf] 3
iguploadfileselected: [ File Path: asb.pdf]
iguploadfileselecting 2

Comment: In my above comment I uploaded 2 files without delay. At last I uploaded 'XP_1.pdf' file which only  fired 'iguploadfileselected & 'iguploadfileuploading' events not 'iguploadfileuploaded' (which is last event).